# How to include migration schema files in webpack build

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, nestjs, migrate-mongo

## Issue

When building the application with Webpack into a single bundle, the library `migrate-mongo` is unable to find the migration schema module eg `migrations/[some-number]-[some-name]-migration.js`. This is probably due to the dynamic import of the migration module by the library itself and because webpack replaces how `require` loads modules.

How can I configure Webpack that it registers the migration js files in it's build, so when the library calls the require it will be able to retrieve the modules.

Library tries requires the module in the following absolute path strategy:

```js
// Roughly
path.join(pwd(), migrationsDir, fileName)
```

**Error received**

`Could not migrate up [file-name]-migration.js. Cannot find module [absolute-path]/migrations/[file-name]-migration.js`

Even though the file exists, tried multiple relative locations just to be sure.

## State

I'm using **Webpack** for building **Nest.js** application and `migrate-mongo` for migrations in an **NX project**. Migration files are located in `migrations/` directory and migration up is triggered by application on startup. Migration works normally when app is started in development mode.

**migrate.ts**

```js
// This function is executed on app bootstrap
export const migrate = async (): Promise<void> => {
  Logger.log('[Migration]: Started');
  config.set(createConfig());
  const {db, client} = await database.connect();
  const migrated = await up(db, client);
  migrated.forEach((fileName) => {
    Logger.log(`[Migration]: migrated ${fileName}`);
  });
  Logger.log('[Migration]: End');
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /other-app/],
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json'),
      }),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/apps/my-backend'),
    filename: 'src/main.js',
  },
  externals: [
    nodeExternals(),
  ],
  plugins: [/* ... */],
}
```

## Tried solutions

- Tried using **CopyPlugin** to copy the migrations, but as found out all modules are placed within the built bundle.
- Tried updating **externals** to include the directory with migrations
- Tried requiring or importing the file and directory in app to register the modules